# PostgreSQL CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE inside a plpgsql function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, temp-tables

I am trying to create a function that does this:

```
drop table t_rv_openitem;
select * into t_rv_openitem from rv_openitem;
select * from t_rv_openitem;
```

I am confused sometimes when it comes to functions in PostgreSQL and get this error:

> An error has occurred:
>
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DROP" LINE 3: DROP TABLE
>   t_rv_openitem;

I know this seems like a simple task but I am pulling my hair out trying to figure this out.

Here is the full function create statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION adempiere.update_t_rv_openitem()
  RETURNS rv_openitem AS
$BODY$

Drop table t_rv_openitem;
select * into t_rv_openitem from rv_openitem;
select * From t_rv_openitem;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION adempiere.update_t_rv_openitem() OWNER TO adempiere;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand above what? I've added the entire function create statement, does that help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add BEGIN and END

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION adempiere.update_t_rv_openitem()
  RETURNS rv_openitem AS
$BODY$

BEGIN -- ADD THIS

Drop table t_rv_openitem;
select * into t_rv_openitem from rv_openitem;
select * From t_rv_openitem;

END; -- AND THIS

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION adempiere.update_t_rv_openitem() OWNER TO adempiere;
```

You don't need BEGIN and END block if you are using `LANGUAGE sql`, you need those though if you are using `LANGUAGE plpgsql`

**UPDATE**

Regarding `ERROR: syntax error at "t_rv_openitem" DETAIL: Expected record variable...`. There's no syntax error on your code, you just need to change this:

```
select * into t_rv_openitem from rv_openitem;
```

To this:

```
create table t_rv_openitem as
select * from rv_openitem;
```

The table creation using `SELECT * INTO tablehere FROM tableSource` works only if you are using it outside of PLPGSQL; when that code struct is inside PLPGSQL, the semantic will be different, it means:

```
SELECT * INTO declaredVariableHere FROM tableSource;
```

To make table creation work on both stand-alone statement and inside PLPGSQL, just use:

```
CREATE TABLE AS SELECT * FROM tableSourceHere;
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I get this
ERROR:  syntax error at "t_rv_openitem"
DETAIL:  Expected record variable, row variable, or list of scalar variables following INTO.
CONTEXT:  compilation of PL/pgSQL function "update_t_rv_openitem" near line 5


********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at "t_rv_openitem"
SQL state: 42601
Detail: Expected record variable, row variable, or list of scalar variables following INTO.
Context: compilation of PL/pgSQL function "update_t_rv_openitem" near line 5

Comment: True it(`SELECT * INTO newTable FROM sourceTable`) does not work in plpgsql, but it does work when it is run as stand-alone statement. That confuses me also before, same syntax yet it will have different semantic when it is placed inside the procedural language

Comment: @DanWalmsley: [`SELECT INTO` is used for this purpose in plpgsql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW)